# "Missing Operating System" when booting from USB flash drive

Tags: usb, flash, drive

Arrghh...So frustrated with this problem.

Today I downloaded the most recent Ubuntu, being completely new to Linux. My plan is to run it on a partitioned drive with Windows 7 on a separate SSD.

Anyway I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 ISO and THEN downloaded the Pen Drive Linux USB Installer. After using that to format my USB drive properly and then put the ISO on the drive, I restarted and entered the boot menu via the POST screen. I selected USB-HDD and it restarted as usual. But after POST it came up with the message "Missing Operating System" on a black screen. I have also tried putting the flash drive to highest boot priority in the BIOS, to no avail.

So does anyone have a solution to this problem? I've seen many questions on this before but nothing helps.

Regards

Comment: I used unetbootin but exactly the same thing happened. Anyway, what do you mean, msy? I haven't done anything like that. Are you sayin I should download another Linux distro?

Comment: you should use a newer version of Ubuntu, if your on 64 bit machine then use 18.04 LTS or 18.10, if on 32 bit then use 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

You shuold take an eye on these things:

- Don't connect other disk to your computer.
- Don't use unreliable tools.
- Don't download incomplete system files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/):

and make your own bootable ubuntu flash disk in 3 easy steps ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the USB installer.

Comment: didn't work. do you think there could be something wrong with my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) over unetbootin. In the more recent...years(?) unetbootin has been causing issues with newer UEFI systems.

If you didn't partition your main drive, you definitely want to remove the USB, boot into Windows, and create either a recovery USB for your bootloader or a backup of your system before dual booting. Windows has the tools for both in the control panel.

To install Ubuntu, enter BIOS and change boot mode from UEFI to legacy so that your computer is able to read the USB-HDD option, or reformat the USB drive with Rufus and try again. Another option to check is if is USB virtualization on, to enable booting from USBs.

Just realized this was bumped from 2014...hope you fixed it!